# How to move from one window to another in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'm working on a WPF UI and for now I have a login window and a MainWindow with multiple userControls inside the MainWindow, now when the app starts it opens the login window, how can I move to the MainWindow and close the login window when I click on the login button??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply close the login window and open the main window.

eg. on a Button Click

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
     this.Close();
     (new MainWindow()).Open();
}
```

The only thing to keep in mind is the specified `ShutdownMode` the default is `OnLastWindowClose`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.shutdownmode?view=netframework-4.8

If you want to stick with the default `ShutdownMode` you could do the following

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
     this.Hide(); //first hide the LoginWindow
     (new MainWindow()).Open();
     this.Close(); //now close the LoginWindow, and the "MainWindow" will be the LastWindow
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, it worked.